# Take the taylor series of nested function?

Tags: calculus

I'm reading Landau&Lifshitz mechanics. They have a functional form $$L(v'^2)=L(v^2+e^2+2e \cdot v)$$ where $e$ and $v$ are velocity vectors and $\cdot$ denotes dot product. They expand the function to first-order in powers of $e$ and get

$$L(v^2) + \frac{dL}{d(v^2)} 2v \cdot e + \text{higher order terms}$$

I don't understand where the $2v$ in the 2nd term comes from?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23098/deriving-the-lagrangian-for-a-free-particle?lq=1

Comment: I saw that, but it doesn't answer my question. I have no issue accepting Landau's proof-- my question is purely mathematical. Mathematica produces the same result using Series[] and it knows nothing about the physics. There is just some taylor expansion magic i don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have L&L in front of me at the moment, so I'll have to infer from the form of your question that $v'=v+e$, where $e$ is a small change in the velocity of the particle/system. If this is correct, here is the logic:

$v'^2=(v+e)^2=(v+e)\cdot (v+e)=v\cdot v+v\cdot e+e\cdot v+e\cdot e=v^2+e^2+2(v\cdot e)$.

Since $e$ is small, $e^2$ and $2v\cdot e$ are also small. This is the necessary condition for a Taylor Expansion:
$$
f(x+\epsilon)=f(x)+f'(x)*\epsilon+f''(x)*\frac{\epsilon^2}2+f'''(x)*\frac{\epsilon^3}6+O(\epsilon^4).
$$

From here it is a simple matter of re-writing your variables the way that you want, namely $x=v^2$, $\epsilon=e^2+2v\cdot e$, and $f\rightarrow L$:
$$
L(v'^2)=L+\frac{dL}{d(v'^2)}*(2v\cdot e)+O(e^2)\\ {(\text{evaluated at }v'^2=v^2)}
$$